# Why do the same object has different ids?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

```
a = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], requires_grad=True)
b = torch.tensor([5.0, 5.0, 5.0])
loss = sum(a*b)
loss.backward()
a.grad = torch.tensor([5., 6., 7.])
print(id(a.grad))
print(id(a.grad))
print(id(a.grad))
```

the output is:

```
2315675408352
2315675409864
2315676143832
```

Shouldn't the id of a.grad be the same value? In my opinion, a.grad pointed to torch.tensor([5., 6., 7.]), so every time I call id(), I should get the same value. Is there anything wrong? I would appreciate it if you could help me solve this problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's [documented](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.grad.html) to be a property, so it can compute something fresh every time you access it.

Toy example showing similar behaviour ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nU4xCsMwDNz9Co02pMGhS1soFPKMkMFEThNIbCG7Q17v2mlo995yOu50Em1x8u58IU5pZL8CG4eZ5pU8x13NLgoxLCYEaG8CMh7EnizHbVdoR3iyQRnsMqpPoqDIevIL1obIOpRHmWy01hVcM5T6ptnGF7vfUndq@t0sAu7Q9fmJzK1UgrjUDHW5WsGMx6j@clJ6Aw)):

```
from random import randint

class C:
    @property
    def grad(self):
        self.hold.append(randint(1000, 9999))
        return self.hold[-1]
    hold = []

c = C()
print(c.grad, id(c.grad))
print(c.grad, id(c.grad))
print(c.grad, id(c.grad))
```

Output:

```
8814 140712555303728
4836 140712555304048
1922 140712555303952
```